# Consulta de registros duplicados MySQL(solo los primeros dos)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subconsultas

Buenas,

Soy algo novato en esto de las subconsultas, tengo una tabla que registra direcciones ip de equipos conectados al día, mi idea es listar solo los primeros dos o un equipos correspondientes a una dirección ip me explico (tabla equipos)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi consulta actual, claro muestra todo:

```
SELECT id_host, hostname, dir_ip, fecha_reg where DATE(fecha_reg) = CURDATE()
```

Favor puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Qué versión de MySQL está usando?.

En la próxima versión de MySQL (8.0) usted podrá utilizar Funciones Ventana ([12.19 Window Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html)), aquí un ejemplo, en MariaDB, donde ya está implementada la funcionalidad ([Window Functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/window-functions/)):

```sql
SELECT
  `der`.`id_host`,
  `der`.`hostname`,
  `der`.`dir_ip`,
  `der`.`fecha_reg`,
  `dir_ip_rank`
FROM (
  SELECT
    `id_host`,
    `hostname`,
    `dir_ip`,
    `fecha_reg`,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY `dir_ip` ORDER BY `id_host`) AS `dir_ip_rank`
  FROM `equipos`
) `der`
WHERE `der`.`dir_ip_rank` <= 2;
```

Ver [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=5e54177e26e5e70f1398e0ced033b82f).

Mientras en MySQL implementan la funcionalidad de Funciones Ventana, una opción es usar una consulta como la siguiente:

```sql
SELECT
  `der`.`id_host`,
  `der`.`hostname`,
  `der`.`dir_ip`,
  `der`.`fecha_reg`,
  `der`.`dir_ip_rank`
FROM (
  SELECT
    `id_host`,
    `hostname`,
    `dir_ip`,
    `fecha_reg`,
    @`dir_ip_rank` := IF(@`dir_ip_current` = `dir_ip`, @`dir_ip_rank` + 1, 1) `dir_ip_rank`,
    @`dir_ip_current` := `dir_ip`
  FROM `equipos`,
    (SELECT
      @`dir_ip_rank` := 0,
      @`dir_ip_current` := ''
    ) `der`
  ORDER BY `dir_ip`, `id_host`, `dir_ip_rank`
) `der`
WHERE `der`.`dir_ip_rank` <= 2;
```

Ver [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i615BUCJZNp1BUfhC2xUYi/0).

Ajuste las consultas como necesite.

**NOTA:** No estoy seguro como usted almacena las direcciones IP, en mi ejemplo, utilicé VARCHAR(15) para efecto del ejemplo, sin embargo, es recomendable usar las funciones [INET_ATON()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) e [INET_NTOA()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa).

Comment: Gracias, es justo lo que necesitaba, si bien es cierto en el ejemplo las tablas fueron para demostrar  y sea entendible, la adapte con los joins y funciona de maravilla, Saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Creo que puedes utilizar el limit=2 para limitar el número de registros que devuelve la consulta.

```
SELECT id_host, hostname, dir_ip, fecha_reg  where DATE(fecha_reg) = CURDATE() limit 2
```

[Aqui te explican como usar el LIMIT](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/select_limit.php)

[Aquí también te explican los diferentes usos que le puedes dar a limit](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx)

El segundo enlace lo explica mejor

Espero que te sirva =)

Comment: Hola Kat. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio.  Las respuestas que son solo un enlace no se consideran de calidad. Has de explicar en la respuesta lo que en el enlace explican ya que si ese enlace se rompiera , tu respuesta quedaria sin sentido. Mira [answer] para aprender a hacer mejores respuestas. Un saludo

Comment: Esto igual no resuelve el problema..porque solo va a devolver 2 registros, y no los primeros dos por IP.